# Expression Tree naming conventions

Tags: naming-conventions, expression-trees

Just a simple question, there aren't a lot of people I know that use Expression Trees so I don't see a lot of resources on how to name them. How would you name an expression variable? Pref. no Hungarian Notations.

For now I just go with:

```
var newItem = Expression.New(typeof(T));
var itemProperty = Expression.Property(newItem,propertyInfo);
```

Comment: Not a question? Why so? I'm asking for a common naming convention for expression tree variables.

Answer (score 2):

I would call it newExpression and memberExpression perhaps.

To be honest though, I try to limit the number of expression variables I have (i'm content with really long expression declarations that span many lines), obviously parameterexpressions for parameters/variables i declare seperately and I name them as such (ie itemParameter, listVariable)